# Why should I use a DialogFragment with an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

`DialogFragment#onCreateDialog`'s javadoc says the following:

> This is typically used to show an AlertDialog instead of a generic
>   Dialog; when doing so `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
>   Bundle)` does not need to be implemented since the AlertDialog takes
>   care of its own content.

It appears that `onCreateView` isn't even called when I create my own `AlertDialog` instead of calling `super.onCreateDialog`. What is the value of `DialogFragment` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the docs say:

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid
>   instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following
>   subclasses:
>
> AlertDialog A dialog that can show a title, up to three buttons, a
>   list of selectable items, or a custom layout. DatePickerDialog or
>   TimePickerDialog A dialog with a pre-defined UI that allows the user
>   to select a date or time. Avoid ProgressDialog
>
> These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you
>   should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The
>   DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your
>   dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the
>   Dialog object.
>
> Using DialogFragment to manage the dialog ensures that it correctly
>   handles lifecycle events such as when the user presses the Back button
>   or rotates the screen. The DialogFragment class also allows you to
>   reuse the dialog's UI as an embeddable component in a larger UI, just
>   like a traditional Fragment (such as when you want the dialog UI to
>   appear differently on large and small screens).

What I get from that is that `DialogFragment` is still responsible for lifecycle events and gives the underlying `Dialog` more re-usability by allowing it to be inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: But since I can't use `DialogFragment#onCreateView`, is it still reusable? It seems like it wouldn't be. What benefit is there to using `DialogFragment` lifecycle events instead of `Dialog` lifecycle events?

Comment: Ok so I just created a new blank project and copied and pasted from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog and `onCreateView()` is being called.

Comment: Yes, but it's called _before_ `onCreateView`, so you still have to manually create your view in `onCreateDialog`.

Comment: Exactly. plus, in some cases, if onCreateView does not return null, it crashes.